# Why does fusing iron in a stellar core use more energy than it releases

Tags: supernova

I know larger stars can fuse heavier and heavier elements up to iron where it stops because fusing iron requires more energy than it releases, causing a collapse and supernova.

Why does fusing iron in a stellar core use more energy than it releases?

Comment: This is rather a physic question that can be answered by quantic mechanics considerations... In short Iron is a very stable state for matter.

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168237/why-does-fusion-stop-at-iron-when-nickel-is-most-tightly-bound

Comment: See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/36719/what-effects-besides-mass-defect-cause-the-alpha-ladder-beyond-iron-56-nickel

Answer (score 2):

> Why does fusing iron in a stellar core use more energy than it releases?

It doesn't, at least not in the alpha ladder. The alpha ladder starts with the carbon-12 produced by the triple alpha process. A carbon-12 and an alpha particle (helium-4) combine to form oxygen-16, which in turn combines with an alpha particle to form neon-20, and so on, up to titanium-44, chromium-48, then iron-52, then nickel-56, and then zinc-60.

It's the production of zinc-60 that kills stars rather than the production of nickel-56. The reactions up to and including the production of nickel-56 are exothermic (i.e., they release heat). The production of zinc-60 is endothermic (it consumes heat, in the form of a gamma particle). The energy-producing reactions that kept the star from collapsing on itself end. Moreover, the temperatures needed to produce zinc-60 are so very high that photons can photodisintegrate zinc-60, recreating the nickel-56 nuclei and alpha particles that created those zinc-60 nuclei. The alpha ladder pretty much stops with nickel-56. (Other processes create elements beyond nickel.)

The nickel-56 ejected from supernovae is rather short-lived, decaying with a half life of 6 days into cobalt-56. This too is radioactive, decaying with a half life of 77 days into iron-56. The unique signatures of these two decays, and the slightly delayed transition from nickel-56 decay to cobalt-56 decay, are one of the key signs that a supernova has occurred.

Comment: Alpha capture would continue (at a very small energy cost), but requires temperatures that produce photons that can photodisintegrate the nuclei.

Comment: Actually, the addition of an alpha particle to 56Ni is exothermic.

Comment: @ProfRob Indeed! I calculate 2.69 MeV for that reaction, which is substantially smaller than the energy released in the other [alpha ladder reactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_process), but it's certainly exothermic. :) (I used atomic masses not nuclide masses in my calculation, I assume that's ok). A slightly confusing note in the [silicon-burning article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon-burning_process) mentions it's exothermic. Actually, both of those articles could do with some clean-up & a clearer explanation of the significance of the photodisintegration energy.

Comment: FWIW, here's the [details of my calculation](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwtzkFuwyAQBdA9pxgpmzgFzGBIIVJXlZftBaosrJrEjlRsg2tLOX3HSdl8ad58NDv4aHIOGS5p-IFunsd8Kst1XWP7LW9NaOR1kLex_Px9L1ns4Q2sld5o1M46xcG-6lp4do-beBJ0hJXncPRmky6QGKmUPqpKW4MVUS0QWduQ-AqloZbSRsNOu1o4NtE89l_qDC_QhS0F3CMlCyk9Df_tkWR4ZmPq47yfONBSwS5Dggx9hL1ADnQoFicG9Bb6YKJSPtDeY_IsLhyWQ9sUfzxsRjA=&lang=sage)

Comment: @PM2Ring see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/36719/what-effects-besides-mass-defect-cause-the-alpha-ladder-beyond-iron-56-nickel

Comment: @ProfRob Thanks for reminding me about that question. I should've checked my bookmarks...